# Who was the actor in C-Chute?

Tags: isaac-asimov, actor-identification

In *Nightfall One*, Asimov says this about a radio adaptation of *C-Chute*:

> Once television came in, I found that voice, and matched the face to it, and that *looked* like Mullen. … I have carefully refrained from learning the actor’s real name. I want him to remain Mullen.

There’s a recording of [the dramatisation](https://youtu.be/uA3ndr7Sm54), which doesn’t have credits. They might have been removed by the uploader, or maybe weren’t there to start with.

Do we know who played Mullen in C-Chute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't answer the actual question, since the individual parts aren't credited and I haven't found any specifically attributed recordings of the individual actors to try to identify the actor by voice.

However the entire episode is available on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/XMinus1_A/xminusone_560208_C-Chute.mp3) including the credits.  The credited actors are:  Lyle Sudrow, Stan Early, Bob Hastings, Mercer McLeod, Danny Ocko and John Gibson, along with the announcer Bill McCort.

If the actors are credited in order of appearance, then Mullen would be played by John Gibson, or possibly, if the same actor played the suicidal Poliarkitis brother, Danny Ocko.

Comment: Thanks, this is likely as close as we can get.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be Lyle Sudrow, at least to my ears. He's Bill here:

(also the guy in the soap commercial) - Lyle played him until 1959